# Collapse events not triggering Bootstrap 2.3.2 JQuery 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something after the accordion div opens but "shown" nor "show" event doesn't fire after the accordion opens

```
$(document).on('show shown shown hide hidden', '.accordion-field', function(){
    console.log('got it'); 
});
```

NOTE: accordion-field are generated dynamically after processing some json coming via ajax.

Anyone knows why this is not working.

EDIT:

After adding a static div (not created via code but written on the html) I realized the event fires.

```
$(document).on('show shown hide hidden', '#xdiv81', function(){
    console.log('got it');
} );
```

How can I do the same for dynamically generated divs

Comment: Does this work in other versions of jQuery.. Do you know if its only a issue with `1.10`?

Comment: I haven't check any other version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vizkos has mentioned, the problem was that I was binding the div to the "shown" and "hidden" events BEFORE the elements were generated.

The solution was to move the biding after the generation.

```
generateDivs();
$(document).on('show shown hide hidden', '#xdiv81', function(){
    console.log('got it');
} );
```

or

```
generateDivs();
$('#xdiv81').on('show shown hide hidden', function(){
    console.log('got it');
}
```

the latter being more efficient.